# C# Visual Studio doesn't recognize ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a downloader tool for a project at work, and I'm trying to create a function to unzip a zip file and extract the contents to a temporary directory. (I'm using Visual Studio Professional, version 4.5.1.)

However, even after adding System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll to my references, visual studio still doesn't recognized the ExtractToDirectory method. The error message tells me "Ionic.Zip.ZipFile does not contain a definition for 'ExtractToDirectory'".

Anyone know how to fix this so that I can extract my files? Here is my code (the file path for the zip is passed in):

```
    private void UnzipStation(string zipPath)
    {
        try
        {          
            string newFp = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "CommissioningFiles");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newFp);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, newFp);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Error unzipping station files. Contact a Novar representative. \n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }


    }
```

Comment: paste full exception with stakc trace somewhere

Comment: @MajkeloDev How do you expect him to post an exception and stack trace if it doesn't compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error message tells me "Ionic.Zip.ZipFile does not contain a definition for 'ExtractToDirectory'".

You have two classes named `ZipFile` that are "available" to the compiler. The C# compiler is confused about which one you are trying to use. It thinks you want to use `Ionic.Zip.ZipFile`, when you really want to use `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`.

You can solve this in two ways. The first, is fully specify the namespace of the `ZipFile` class you want to use:

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, newFp);
```

Or, you can add a `using` directive at the top of your C# file:

```
using ZipFile = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile;
```

Comment: I had to use both the using statement and the explicit namespace (as well as removing the reference to Ionic), but that finally did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have a reference and using statement for DotNetZip in your project (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile). If you decided to stop using it and start using System.IO.Compression, delete this using statement and the reference. If you still use DotNetZip elsewhere, use `System.IO.Compression.Zipfile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath,newFp);` to explicitly use the ZipFile class from System.IO.Compression.

Answer (score 0):

to use Ionic.Zip you have to do that :

```
using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath))
{
     zipFile.ExtractAll(newFp);
}
```